# undefined method `user_path' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

_app_views_pins__pin_html_erb__600263857_22928508
app/views/pins/_pin.html.erb

```
3     <p class="description">
4         <%= pin.description %>
5     </p>
6     <p>
7         <strong>
8             Posted by <%= link_to pin.user.name, pin.user %>
9         </strong>
10     </p>
11     <% if current_user == pin.user %>
12        <p>
13            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
```

Line 8 is the problem. Would be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: run `rake routes` and have the route you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is stating that `pin.user` isn't a route. The `link_to` helper requires a valid route.

Run `rake routes` to see which routes are available. Also, check out [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to become more familiar with Rails routing.